# My validation loops are not working properly

Tags: python, loops, validation

I am trying to validate that code inputted by a user is a binary string that is between 4 and 12 characters long. As it is now, it does not validate that it is a binary string or between 4 and 12 characters long

Here's the section of my code that I am referring to:

```
binaryNumber = input('Enter a binary number between 4 and 12 bits: ')

numberSet = set(binaryNumber)
binary = {'0','1'}
while len(binaryNumber) < 4 and len(binaryNumber) > 12:
    while numberSet != binary or numberSet != {'0'} or numberSet != {'1'}: 
        binaryNumber = input('Invalid entry! Please enter a binary number between 4 and 12 bits: ')
```

Could you tell me what I need to revise, so that I can make it work? Thank you in advance!

I tried the number 1. I tried using numbers besides 0 and 1.

Comment: `while len(binaryNumber) < 4 and len(binaryNumber) > 12` This loop will never run.  There is no number that is less than 4 and also greater than 12.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition in the first while loop should be "or" instead, not "and", as the length of the binary number will not be both less than 4 and greater than 12 at the same time.

Some edits to your code, with a cleaner structure (subjectively) and a `else: break` when the input is correct (optional):

```
binaryNumber = input('Enter a binary number between 4 and 12 bits: ')

while True:
    numberSet = set(binaryNumber)
    binary = {'0', '1'}
    if len(binaryNumber) < 4 or len(binaryNumber) > 12 or not numberSet.issubset(binary):
        binaryNumber = input('Invalid entry! Please enter a binary number between 4 and 12 bits: ')
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate your answer. Other than 'and' needing to be changed to an 'or', do you know why my code didn't work? I'm just trying to understand, so I can avoid doing the same mistake in the future.

Comment: I figured it out! My code works just fine if I just add the break command! Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I have an infinite loop if I don't add break

Comment: Glad that you've found the correct solution! Do accept my answer as a solution if that helped :D

Comment: Please tell me how would I do that?